# is it possible to set read preference at mongoose query level

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a mongo DB cluster with 1 primary and 2 secondaries. The replication lag is usually around 15 seconds. There are some critical sections of my code where we write and immediately read, which will end up in dirty reads. So I am exploring an option where I can pass read pref as an option at the query level.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myapp');
var MyModel = mongoose.model('Test', new Schema({ name: String }));
MyModel.findOne({'name':'dinesh'}) // thinking of sending read pref here
```

When I call `findOne`, is there a way to pass read pref in the query itself or do I have to do it while connecting to mongo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [findOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) accepts an options object that can include a read preference.

> Model.findOne()
>
> Parameters
>
> [conditions] «Object»
> [projection] «Object|String|Array» optional fields to return, see Query.prototype.select()
> [options] «Object» optional see Query.prototype.setOptions()
> [callback] «Function»
> Returns:
>
> «Query»